# Use EBS-CSI into self-hosted k8s cluster in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I have hosted my K8s cluster on AWS EC2. I want to use AWS EBS Self-provisioning into my k8s cluster for PVC.so I came across EBS-CSI but I can't find the document that can help me to install into my self hosted cluster.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html

Answer (score 0):

If you've provisioned your cluster using kOps, it can be addded as an add-on
[ebs-csi add-on](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/addons/#self-managed-aws-ebs-csi-driver) or via helm [ebs-csi helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/tree/master)